# C++ How to implement interprocess socket communication?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, interprocess

I would like to setup interprocess communication using sockets between a server and several client processes using C++. The server and all client processes will be running on the on the same Windows 7 computer. The intention is that a `std::vector` of data will be held by the server and transmitted to each client. From time-to-time the vector held by the server will be extended (`push_back()`) with further data elements and the extra data will need to be transmitted to each client.  Can anyone provide links to examples of how to do this, relevant reference materials or a simple 'toy' code example?

EDIT:  After further investigation I have found that Winsock would be suitable.  There are plenty of examples revealed from a Google search on how to setup a Winsock server & client arrangement.  HOWEVER there is less information on how to actually pass data through the sockets.  Can anyone expand on how to synchronize an `std::vector` between a server and clients through socket communication?  Each client would need to indicate which element index it has already been passed and the server would serve up only those elements which the client did not already have.

Comment: If this is not homework, you probably want to go for [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)

Comment: This is a reasonable question, reasonably well put, so do not be insulted if I have voted to close it.  The question is probably too broad for Stack Overflow's format.  If you can think of a way greatly to narrow your question, once the present question in fact has been closed, then feel free to try again.

Comment: It's not homework, I promise!  Just a lengthy endeavor to accomplish an end goal.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to control the protocol above the tcp/udp layer, try [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). If you are more interested in just being able to pass messages, then look at something like [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) or [AMQP](http://amqp.org/).

Server example using ZeroMQ

```
#include <iostream>
#include <zmq.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    // create a ZeroMQ network context using 1 thread
    zmq::context_t ctx(1);

    // We are 'UPSTREAM' i.e. a receiver
    zmq::socket_t sock(ctx, ZMQ_UPSTREAM);

    sock.connect("tcp://localhost:12345");

    zmq::message_t msg;
    while (sock.recv(&msg)) {
        std::cout << "rx: " << (const char*)msg.data() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're comparing apples to oranges. libevent and boost asio are frameworks to transform blocking-IO into non-blocking IO. ZeroMQ actually just provides a new type of sockets which can be wrapped by aforementioned frameworks. I don't know AMQP but I assume it's similar.

Comment: I was not comparing them so much as offering two routes to get started on research. Both paths are great routes to bootstrapping someone from not knowing how to do socket programming to having working socket solutions. I find libevent preferable to Boost because I haven't worked on any projects that use Boost and I have a C background. Both AMQP and ZeroMQ work quite well for the type of problem described without the use of additional libraries, as per the example code.

Comment: @kfsone Thanks for the ZeroMQ tip.  I've read its introductory documentation.  Seems like it could be an answer.  I'd like to try it out on my Windows 7 64 bit PC using Visual Studio 2012 Express; the installation instructions though are as clear as mud.  Not even sure which file I need to download, let alone how to install & link it in a project!  Got any tips? Thanks.

Comment: Go to the (front page)[http://www.zeromq.org/] and click "Get", and download the "Windows Installers" under "Stable Release"

Answer (score 0):

If the processes are always going to run on the same server, you might consider using [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) instead of sockets to handle communications.

Comment: OK thanks; I have arrived at the idea of using socket programming as an alternative to Boost::Interprocess after running into trouble (a bug I think) trying to work with & synchronize access to Boost::Interprocess shared memory resources.